# how to create a view with recent item also display catagary name

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I  want  a  block on my home page called (recent files addit) but I  want to display catagary name also like file name  (how to create a folder) catagary: (basic computer learning)  you can find same example on this website home page www.blindhelp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to create a Views block showing recently uploaded Files and Taxonomy terms the nodes where files are attached belong to is to add a Relationship  to the content the file is attached to. You can start with `Files` Views type (assuming Drupal 7):

1. Create a new View of type `File`, set the Format to `Table`
2. Add a new `Relationship` **File Usage: Content**. This will introduce info from the node the file is attached to into this View
3. Now you can add the usual Filters (for example **Content: Type (= Article)** and **Content: File:fid (not empty)**). They will automatically be configured to use the Relationship you created in the previous step
4. **File: Name** field should already be there. Add a new field: **Content: All taxonomy terms (All taxonomy terms)**
5. Add `Sort criteria` **File: Upload date (desc)**, adjust the Pager, and other relevant Views properties you want.

Comment: or if I want to display node with turm name like my node is (how to create a folder) and its turm is basic computer

Comment: It's very similar to display Nodes and their terms. In the first step create Views of type "Content", restrict to Content type you're using (for example Articles). You don't need step 2 or 3 (we don't need a Relationship or to check there are no files attached.) In step 4 you'll already have the Title field present and you add a new field that shows Taxonomy terms. The Sort criteria will probably be "Authored on" date. Or if you want you can show all three information together - Node title, File name, Taxonomy term, just add the Node title field in Step 4 of my answer.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it :)

Comment: beautiful its work now finally near to achieve my gol with the help of your answers i have almost 16 content type so i can not restrict Content type on one content type. how to i manage this or its not possible?

Comment: You don't have to restrict Content types at all, you can have Views that display Nodes of all Content types. To achieve that when creating a new View select to Show **Content** of type **All**, or if you already have the View, simply don't include any Filter that restricts Content types. If you are following steps in my Answer, in step 3 click on **Content: Type (= Article)** and **Remove** so you won't have any Content type restrictions. Or keep the Filter but edit the selection to include all Content types.